# Delete [make-unique]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

I came across this tag ([make-unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/make-unique)) and wasn't sure it can constitute as a tag so much as C++ function. Per the deletion guideline:

1. It doesn't so much describe it as much as it literally states the function name and even more specifically in a given language (C++). Tags should be generic enough to bring together searches, not based on specific code methods or classes.
2. It is, but again, very specific. We already have [smart-pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/smart-pointers), [pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pointers), [unique-ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unique-ptr) tags that are more generic but still very applicable.
3. I don't see anything meaningful added here, the value "make-unique" is correctly seen in the title of the question, why repeat it as a tag?
4. Again, it will always mean [make-unique], although this could be used by other users as a tag to say a question involving how to select unique items in a list. To which, it would become even more useless.

I enjoyed the thoughtful questions for tag deletion, hopefully I added enough thought. If not, I will certainly add more. This is my first burniate after all.

I modified the [only question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26379311/make-unique-initializer-list) utilizing this tag to use [unique-ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unique-ptr) instead. (I know I don't have editing rights, but since it was just one, it would not be a big hassle)

Comment: If there's only one question and you removed it already, you probably don't need to worry as it should delete itself in less than a week.

Comment: @Poke: The orphaned-tag remover runs daily.

Comment: @Deduplicator Ok, thanks for the correction.  (though I no longer can edit my comment due to it being too old)

Comment: Thanks, i read about the question-less tags being deleted, but wasn't clear if it also included tags that at one point had questions, but due to editing returned zero questions. Thanks for clearing it up!

Comment: @mateuscb: tags can't exist without having had at least one question - the only way to create them is to attach them to a question.

Comment: [tag:unique-ptr] is the perfect category for questions about `std::make_unique`.  You did the right thing by retagging that.